# Dans la phrase "une belle jeune fille, elle l'a été(e)", le participe "été" ne s'accorde pas avec "l"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, accord, syntaxe, passé-composé

Dans la phrase "une belle jeune fille, elle l'a été(e)", le participe "été" ne s'accorde pas avec le "l" apostrophe?

Selon ce que j'ai su, lorsque le COD est placé devant le verbe, le participe s'accorde avec lui. Or, il me semble complétement bizarre de l'accorder, alors j'ai fait une recherche et cela me mène dans une discution ( https://forum.lefigaro.fr/forum/affich-8923-surprise-je-l-ai-etee ). Je me suis donc rendu compte que les verbes d'états comme le verbe "être" n'admettent pas de COD ni de COI mais des attributs.

Alors, est-ce correcte d'écrire "une belle jeune fille, elle l'a été"?

Et d'ailleur, j'ai essayé avec d'autres verbes d'états:

- *Le monstre, elle l'est devenue* --> Est-ce correcte d'écrire cela? À mon avis puisque "l' " n'est pas COD du verbe, on ne l'accorde pas avec, et puis, c'est "elle" qui est devenue (présence de l'auxiliaire "être").

Ayant dit tout cela, je demeure incertain, quelqu'un pourra me corriger?

Comment: Le participe *été* est invariable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une phrase "nominale", comme *Elle est une belle jeune fille.*=*Une belle jeune fille elle est.* Il ne s'agit pas ici de COD, car *une belle jeune fille* pourrait être le sujet de la phrase aussi bien que *elle*. (Dans les langues déclinées, comme l'allemand ou le russe, on dirait que tous les deux sont dans le cas nominatif.)

*Le monstre, elle l'est devenue.* Il s'agit d'un verbe devenir, qui se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire être, donc la participe d'accord avec le sujet.

Comment: « ***C**e monstre*, elle l'est devenue ! » ou éventuellement : « *Monstrueuse*, elle l'est devenue ! » (on peut remplacer le ***!*** par une incise ou un complément d'information justifiant l'évolution de la personne, mais le « ***L**e monstre, elle l'est devenue* » ne fonctionne pas : *monstre* est un nom, *belle* de l'exemple du §1 est un adjectif

Comment: ***Un** monstre, elle l'est devenu**e***

Comment: @Personne merci à vous deux. J'ai simplement repris les examples de la question originale.

Answer (score 1):

Une autre manière de décrire la situation est qu'un participe passé peut selon le cas s'accorder avec le sujet formel ou le complément direct. **Or le groupe nominal qui suit le  verbe être n'est pas un complément, mais un attribut.**

C'est donc un peut la même situation qu'avec les verbes accompagnés d'une quantité qui n'est pas considérée un complément direct (Grevisse parle de "complément adverbial de mesure"): *Les trente milles dollars que ça m'a **couté**.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup! J'ai appris une nouvelle chose. Pour référence, j'ai trouvé ces deux sites qui expliquent l'accord du participe avec les compléments adverbial de mesure ( https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/accord-du-participe-passe-avec-un-complement-de-mesure ) et ( https://motsdescribe.com/accord-du-participe-passe-avec-avoir-le-complement-de-mesure/ ), et woah... le Francais me casse la tête...